# How to get powershell to show onlyIP address and interface alias(-name)

Tags: windows, powershell

I have looked around and have tried to get both the (`-interfaceAlias` or `-Name`) of the NIC card to be displayed along with IP address in a table format.

I have tried to use both the `Get-NetAdaptor` and `Get-NetIpaddress` commands and I can see that can get either the name or the address but can't work out how to get both at the same time

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-Netadapter | get-Netipaddress | Format-table

ifIndex IPAddress                                       PrefixLength PrefixOrigin SuffixOrigin AddressState PolicyStore
------- ---------                                       ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -----------
66      fe80::dc2e:7d51:e01b:6d1b%66                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
66      169.254.109.27                                            16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
60      fe80::8963:5f37:4a1f:9afc%60                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
60      172.22.32.1                                               27 Manual       Manual       Tentative    ActiveStore
60      169.254.154.252                                           16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
25      fe80::a50a:7a1c:3f49:f5df%25                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
25      169.254.245.223                                           16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
25      169.254.2.1                                               23 Manual       Manual       Tentative    ActiveStore
25      169.254.1.1                                               23 Manual       Manual       Tentative    ActiveStore
39      fe80::4c52:9107:fa8c:eb00%39                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
39      169.254.235.0                                             16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
21      fe80::c059:d2f1:5cec:f910%21                              64 WellKnown    Link         Preferred    ActiveStore
21      192.168.3.1                                               27 Manual       Manual       Preferred    ActiveStore
72      fe80::60e7:8001:9fa7:b080%72                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
75      fe80::e86f:786b:3a49:ba98%75                              64 WellKnown    Link         Deprecated   ActiveStore
72      169.254.176.128                                           16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
72      20.20.20.1                                                24 Manual       Manual       Tentative    ActiveStore
75      169.254.186.152                                           16 WellKnown    Link         Tentative    ActiveStore
8       fe80::b4e4:5199:3074:7db%8                                64 WellKnown    Link         Preferred    ActiveStore
8       192.168.248.1                                             23 Manual       Manual       Preferred    ActiveStore
14      fe80::3ceb:65cb:1e1:aa57%14                               64 WellKnown    Link         Preferred    ActiveStore
14      192.168.213.1                                             24 Manual       Manual       Preferred    ActiveStore
4       fe80::5133:490b:9810:6fa%4                                64 WellKnown    Link         Preferred    ActiveStore
```

Which gives this output fine. I am then wanting to take the below to give me the Netadaptor name

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-Netadapter -name "$localName1"

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Onboard_A_SCADA_Route1    Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I21...      22 Disconnected 00-30-A7-21-2D-3D          0 bps
```

What I would like to do is either combine or format the output

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-Netadapter -Name "*" | Format-List -property "name", "Ipaddress"


name : TEAM_PCI5 _(B)-PCI5_(C)_61850_Mirror

name : TEAM_PCI4_(C)-PCI4_(D)_OTN_Copadata

name : TEAM-PCI4_(A)-PCI4_(B)-SCADA Mirror
```

this only gives me the name not ipaddress

I have also tried

```
Get-netadpater -name "$localName1" | Get-IPaddress
```

or

```
Get-netadpater -name "$localName1" | Get-IPaddress |Format-Table
```

neither display an output.

I have looked online and tried various ways and looked at the Microsoft help but can't see how to combine.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean like this? `Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object InterfaceAlias, IPAddress | Format-Table`

Comment: You have a typo in your example get-netad**pa**ter rather than get-netadapter

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) to achieve what you want.

> The `Select-Object` cmdlet selects specified properties of an object or
>   set of objects. It can also select unique objects, a specified number
>   of objects, or objects in a specified position in an array.

When I want to get specific properties, I always run the command I want with `fl *` (alias for [`Format-List *`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7)) to get all the properties returned that exist. e.g:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | fl *


PrefixOrigin             : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin             : Dhcp
Type                     : Unicast
Store                    : ActiveStore
AddressFamily            : IPv4
AddressState             : Preferred
ifIndex                  : 14
Caption                  :
Description              :
ElementName              :
InstanceID               :
CommunicationStatus      :
DetailedStatus           :
HealthState              :
InstallDate              :
Name                     : ;:8:8:8;>:55;>55;55;
OperatingStatus          :
OperationalStatus        :
PrimaryStatus            :
Status                   :
StatusDescriptions       :
AvailableRequestedStates :
EnabledDefault           : 2
EnabledState             :
OtherEnabledState        :
RequestedState           : 12
TimeOfLastStateChange    :
TransitioningToState     : 12
CreationClassName        :
SystemCreationClassName  :
SystemName               :
NameFormat               :
OtherTypeDescription     :
ProtocolIFType           : 4096
ProtocolType             :
Address                  :
AddressOrigin            : 0
AddressType              :
IPv4Address              : 10.0.0.140
IPv6Address              :
IPVersionSupport         :
PrefixLength             : 24
SubnetMask               :
InterfaceAlias           : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex           : 14
IPAddress                : 10.0.0.140
PreferredLifetime        : 6.21:47:25
SkipAsSource             : False
ValidLifetime            : 6.21:47:25
PSComputerName           :
CimClass                 : ROOT/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetIPAddress
CimInstanceProperties    : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties      : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

Then I know what properties fit my needs and I can select the ones I want. You can use:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object InterfaceAlias, IPAddress | Format-Table
```

But keep in mind that the `Format-Table` is only used for you to view it. If you need to do something else with the returned properties, omit the `Format-Table`.

Comment: Thank you for that that is a great explanation as was the information I was missing to construct my ps argument